# chromatic number and subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove that any graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $ \chi(G)=k$ has a subgraph $H$ such that $ H \simeq \overline{K_p}$ where $p=n/k$ and $K_p$ is the complete graph with $n/k$ vertices.

**My attempt:** Because  $ \chi(G)=k$ it must be $G \subseteq K_{p_1 p_2 \cdots p_k} $ where $\displaystyle{\sum_{j=1}^{k} p_j =n}$.

Can I consider now that $ p_j =n/k$ for all j?

If no then the other cases is to have $ p_j >n/k$ for some $j \in \{1, \cdots ,k\}$.

But now how can I continue?

Comment: Someone?? I really need this.

Comment: You just asked an hour ago.  You can't be upset that there's no answer yet.

Comment: @Graphth: I am not upset. Sorry for being so hurry.

Comment: I don't understand the question. There is no reason to believe that $n/k$ is an integer. If it isn't, then what is meant by a graph with a fractional number of vertices? Also, what is meant by that bar over the $K_p$? I thought it might mean complement, but complement with respect to what?

Comment: The color classes are independent sets of average size n/k.

Comment: So, the point is there must exist one independent set of size ceiling of n/k?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\chi(G) = k$, it means we can color the graph with $k$ colors, $c_1, \ldots, c_k$.  Each color class, $c_i$, consists of some vertices $V_i$.  Necessarily, the vertices in $V_i$ are independent, or we could not color them all the same color, $c_i$.

Now, assume that every color class contains less than $n / k$ vertices.  Then the total number of vertices in the graph is $|G| < k \cdot (n/k) = n$.  This isn't possible since we assume $|G| = n$.  Therefore, some color class contains at least $n / k$ vertices.  Since the vertices in a color class are independent, we have an independent set of size at least $n / k$.

Comment: So, OP wants the complement of $H$ to be $K_p$, not, as written, $H$ to be the complement of $K_p$. I think you have successfully decoded the question!

Comment: Thank's for the answer Graphth! I had a mental block.